# Load and show an image from the web in Python with Gtk 3?

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

I'm writing an app on Ubuntu 12.04 with Python and GTK 3. The problem I have is that I can't figure out how I should do to show a Gtk.Image in my app with an image file from the web.

This is as far as I have come:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository.GdkPixbuf import Pixbuf
import urllib2

url = 'http://lolcat.com/images/lolcats/1338.jpg'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
image = Gtk.Image()
image.set_from_pixbuf(Pixbuf.new_from_stream(response))
```

I think everything is correct except the last line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-File-Loading.html#gdk-pixbuf-new-from-stream), `new_from_stream()` needs a `Gio.InputStream` and `Gio.Cancellable` as arguments.

You could also save the image on disk and remove when needed. Here is a very basic example:

```
import os
import urllib2
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository.GdkPixbuf import Pixbuf


def quit_event(widget, event):
    os.remove(imgname)
    Gtk.main_quit()

imgname = '1338.jpg'
url = 'http://lolcat.com/images/lolcats/'+imgname
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
with open(imgname, 'wb') as img:
    img.write(response.read())

image = Gtk.Image()
pb = Pixbuf.new_from_file(imgname)
image.set_from_pixbuf(pb)

window = Gtk.Window()
window.connect('delete-event', quit_event)
window.add(image)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

You should write to a better location though, maybe /tmp or a user-specified dir.